# ElGamal encryption of concatenated messages

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, elgamal-encryption

Suppose an encrypter separately produces three ElGamal ciphertexts $c_1 = E(m_1)$, $c_2 = E(m_2)$ and $c_3 = E(m_3)$, which encrypt the messages $m_1$, $m_2$ and $m_3$, respectively.

Is it possible for the encrypter to prove with a zero-knowledge proof that $m_1$ = $m_2 \mathbin\| m_3 = m_2 \times 2^{32} + m_3$, i.e., that $c_1$ encrypts  the concatenation of the messages $m_2$ and $m_3$?

---

(added by moderator to summarize exchanges with the OP)

- It is used a *variant of* ElGamal encryption, where for plaintext $m$ the group element $g^m$ is what gets encrypted using standard ElGamal.
- In the expression $m_2\mathbin\|m_3$, plaintext integers $m_2$ and $m_3$ are bitstrings *of fixed size (32-bit)*.
- One option for the encrypter/prover is to make use of the ephemeral secret exponents generated at encryption.

Comment: Basically I want to use additive/exponential ElGamal with plaintexts of 64 bits. However, and because decryption requires solving the discrete log problem, I need to decompose the ciphertext of 64 bits in two ciphertexts of 32 bits, where the two 32 bits values concatenated correspond to the 64 bits value.

Comment: With additive/exponential ElGamal I mean encrypt $g^{m_i}$, instead of just the message $m_i$ (https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9000/additive-elgamal-encryption-algorithm), that's why you need to solve the discret log to decrypt. The message space of $m_2$ and $m_3$ is $2^{32}$ and $m_1$ is $2^{64}$, because it is the concatenation of $m_2$ and $m_3$

Comment: This was initially transcribed without essential information, pointing to homework/assignment without showing effort towards a solution. Thus by [our policy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here are hints: exhibit a public function $f$ so that the desired proof is equivalent to proof that $c=f(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ would decrypt to zero; then make a zero-knowledge proof of that. [This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59370/555) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll consider the additively homomorphic variant of ElGamal encryption, in a finite group with generator $g$ of prime order¹ $n$.

The private key is a random secret integer $d$ drawn uniformly randomly in $[0,n)$. The public key is $q\gets g^d$.

Encryption for integer $m$ goes:

- Draw a random secret integer $k$ uniformly randomly in $[0,n)$
- Compute $r\gets g^k$ and $s\gets g^m\cdot q^k$
- Output ciphertext $(r,s)=c$ as the result of encryption of $m$, noted $E(m)$.

Decryption of ciphertext $(r,s)=c$ goes

- Check that $r$ and $s$ are in the group
- Compute $a\gets r^{n-d}\cdot s$
- Find integer $m\in [0,n)$ with $g^m=a$. This requires tractable work for small $m$, using e.g [baby-step/giant-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step). For large $m$, we assume some oracle solves that problem when we write $D(c)$.
- Output $m$ as the result of decryption of $c$, noted $D(c)$.

Note: Encryption $E$ is not a function. $D$ is one.

When $c=(r,s)$ and $c'=(r',s')$, we'll note $c\cdot c'$ for $(r\cdot r',s\cdot s')$; and $c^u$ for $(r^u,s^u)$.

It's easy to show that

- if $0\le m<n$, then $D(E(m))\,=\,m$ [whatever $k$ was drawn by $E$]
- $D(E(m)\cdot E(m'))\,=\,(m+m')\bmod n$
- For any integer $u$ it holds that $D(E(m)^u)\,=\,(m\times u)\bmod n$ [where $\times$ is integer multiplication].

In the following, we assume the $c_i$ have been independently computed as $E(m_i)$ for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$; $m_2$ and $m_3$ are in $[0,2^{32})$; definition of $m_2\mathbin\|m_3$ as $m_2\times2^{32}+m_3$; and $n>m_1$, $n\ge2^{64}$.

---

> (Given the value of such $c_i$) is it possible for the encrypter to prove with a zero-knowledge proof that $m_1\,=\,m_2 \mathbin\| m_3$?

**Yes**, if the encrypter/prover holds the private key $d$: define $c\gets{c_1}^{n-1}\cdot{c_2}^{(2^{32})}\cdot c_3$, and present any skeptical with a Zero-Knowledge Proof that $D(c)=0$ [see next paragraph]. Argue $D(c)=0$ proves $-m_1+m_2\times2^{32}+m_3\bmod n\,=\,0$, thus $m_1\,=\,m_2\times2^{32}+m_3$. The computation of $c$ won't be too tedious, for computing ${c_2}^{(2^{32})}$ requires computing a mere $62$ squares in the group, while ${c_1}^{n-1}$ requires at most $2\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor$ squares and less multiplications, using a [standard method of exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Left-to-right_binary_method).

There remains to make a Zero-Knowledge Proof (ZKP) that $D(c)=0$; that is, with $c=(r,s)$, that it holds $r^{n-d}\cdot s\,=\,g^0$; equivalently, that $r^d=s$. The prover is assumed to know $d$, an can check this directly. The ZKP aims to convince the verifier knowing group elements $g,q,r,s$ that the prover knows $d$ such that $g^d\,=\,q$ and $r^d\,=\,s$. This the Chaum-Pedersen proof of equivalent discrete logarithms, explained [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/15838/555) and [there](https://web.mat.upc.edu/jorge.villar/doc/notes/DataProt/zk.pdf#page=4).

That should convince a rational verifier well versed in math. Good luck with that line of argument facing a random citizen fearing there was fraud in an election.

---

If the encrypter/prover does not hold the private key, but controls or keeps the $k_i$, there ares ways too.

A simple way is that the encrypter/prover generates $k_1$ as $k_1\gets k_2\times2^{32}+k_3$, rather than randomly. This ensures $c_1\,=\,{c_2}^{(2^{32})}\cdot c_3$, which is trivial for anyone to verify. That relation itself allows to prove this choice of $k_1$ [on top of the assumed $m_1=m_2 \mathbin\| m_3$] does not weaken anything. Even simpler, $c_1$ can be computed directly as $c_1\gets{c_2}^{(2^{32})}\cdot c_3$.

Computing and revealing $k\gets k_2\times2^{32}+k_3-k_1$ also does the job: it allows to check $c_1\cdot(g^k,q^k)={c_2}^{(2^{32})}\cdot c_3$, which conclusively proves $D(c_1)\,=\,D(c_2)\mathbin\|D(c_3)$. But I pass at proving my intuition there's nothing useful revealed, and I would not say it's a true ZKP.

But that can be turned to a true ZKP thru the Chaum-Pedersen proof of equivalent discrete logarithms: with $c=(r,s)$ defined as ${c_1}^{n-1}\cdot{c_2}^{(2^{32})}\cdot c_3$, the ZKP aims to convince the verifier knowing group element $g,q,r,s$ that the prover knows $k$ such that $g^k\,=\,r$ and $q^k\,=\,s$.

---

¹ That is: the group has $n$ elements $g^m=\underbrace{g\cdot g\ldots
g}_{m\text{ terms}}$ for $m$ in $[1,n]$, with $g^n$ the group neutral $1$. For security, $n$ is usually a large prime. A simple example would be a [Schnorr group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group).

Comment: @Fiono: I think I now outline valid Zero Knowledge Proofs both for a prover knowing the private key, and for a prover only knowing how the encryption was made. I still refer to another answer or reference for the Chaum-Pedersen proof of equivalent discrete logarithms. I hope I'll be able to put how it works in the answer. But don't hold your breath, that's all I have for you today. For good. Thanks for the question, I learned while answering it.